# Output values inside the array

Tags: php

```
$stock = [
    "marketplace" => [
       "stocks" => 'if($a = 1) {return 6}'
    ]
];
```

How to use the code inside the array value ?

```
return $stock['marketplace']['stocks'];
```

I plan to get in the method

```
if($a = 1) {
  return 6
}
```

Comment: You wish to execute it or simply return it?

Comment: Execute, I want to use this as part of the code

Comment: ok, I wouldn't recommend this approach, so I am out. BTW, `if($a = 1) {` will always be true since it is an assignment. You would rather wish to do `if($a == 1) {`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute the code, you can do:

```
eval($stock['marketplace']['stocks']);
```

but as @nice_dev said it is not recommended to use `eval`